# When should I use fetchInstance method instead of getInstance method? (ObjectStore Object) (IBM Content Engine)

Tags: spring-boot, methods, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

[In the documentation on the official site,](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.11?topic=stores-objectstore-object)

Difference between these methods explained as:

> Use getInstance or fetchInstance to retrieve an existing instance of an ObjectStore object. The difference between these two methods is that getInstance does not verify the existence of the requested object on the server; it returns a local reference to the object, which is not affiliated with a server object until you perform a function on the object (for example, fetch a property value) that causes a round trip to the server. This technique, also called "fetchless instantiation", is useful when the wanted object serves only passively, for example, as the target value of an object-valued property. The fetchInstance method, however, immediately makes a round trip to the server to retrieve the property values of the ObjectStore object.

Problem is, I could not understand the scenarios to use these methods when creating a ObjectStore.

Can someone explain and give basic use case examples?